# Problems with multiple profiles in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After opening Outlook and selecting the profile I want to use I can never get the option to select profiles again until I reboot. I exit Outlook politely. Check to make sure no mapi services are running in task manager. No matter what I try I have to reboot before being presented with selecting the profile again.

Comment: Do you have any add-in installed in Outlook? Try disabling these add-ins or try starting Outlook in safe mode to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: **https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-to-another-outlook-email-profile-be3b617f-3f64-43d3-9037-8313b431803c**

In the **Choose Profile** dialog, select **Options** and **Prompt for a profile to be used**

Make sure that under **Options** the checkbox **Set as default profile** is unchecked.

Comment: Been there done that. I get the option one time, so I at least get it once, then not again until I reboot.